# What to use instead of eval for dynamic code generation/loading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-generation, metaprogramming, eval, dynamic-loading

JavaScript strict mode forbids usage of the eval function. However, I don't see how dynamic code loading/generation can be implemented without it. Are there any new APIs for this? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Question is invalidated by the fact that strict mode doesn't forbid eval, it just disables the dynamic scoping of eval

Comment: @Esailija That too would be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple: Strict mode doesn't forbid eval, it just disables the dynamic scoping of eval:

```
var x;

function y(k) {
    eval(k);
    x = 4; //Under strict mode, this always references the outer x
}
```